# Constraints on Generic Protocols inheriting from Constrained Protocols

Tags: swift, swift4

I am trying to take advantage of generics like so.

```
protocol Y { ... }
protocol X: Y { ... }

protocol A: Collection where Element == Y { ... }
protocol B: A where Element == X { ... }
```

I am getting the error on the definition of `B`:

> Same-type constraint type 'X' does not conform
>   to required protocol 'Y'

But, `X` does conform to `Y`...

I tried using an intermediary associatedtype `DataPoint` like so

```
protocol A: Collection where Element == DataPoint { 
    associatedtype DataPoint: Y
    ... 
}
protocol B: A where DataPoint == X { ... }
```

But I get the same error. Is it possible to accomplish this sort of thing in Swift 4 or do I have to make two completely separate protocols?

Comment: I get a better error message, "Associated type 'Self.Element' cannot be equal to both 'Y' and 'X'" – which makes perfect sense. Surely you meant `Element : Y` & `Element : X`?

Comment: Although "But, `X` does conform to `Y`" – no it doesn't, [protocols don't conform to themselves](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43408193/2976878).

Comment: @Hamish I just understood your first comment as I thought that's what I was doing. Yes, I did mean that, thank you very much.

Comment: New syntax available! `protocol B: A where Element: Y&X`